# Probability - long-run proportion

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

So the problem asks:

> A zoo owns a population of rare Galapagos turtles. The turtles bring in a lot of visitors but unfortunately do not breed in captivity. To maintain the population, new turtles are brought in at a rate of 0.3/year. The scientists are still not sure about the mortality of these species, so for simplicity the zookeeper assumes that the longevity of each turtle has exponential distribution with mean $30$ years. Find the long-run proportion of time when there are two or fewer turtles in the zoo.

My approach:

from the given information, the longevity of each turtle has exponential distribution with mean = 1/$\theta$ = $30$ yrs

Therefore, the longevity follows exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$ $= 1/30=0.033yrs $

By the probability distribution of exponential distribution, 
$p(x≤2)=p(x=0)+p(x=1)+p(x=2)$

$=0.033e^{-0.033*0}+0.033e^{-0.033*1}+0.033e^{-0.033*2}$

$=0.0639$

Is this the right approach to do these kinds of problems?

Comment: Is time assumed continuous or discrete?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Actually I am not sure, the question is a little bit confusing.

Comment: If you extended your sum over all non-negative integer $x$, so $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac1{30}e^{-x/30}$ it would add up to slightly more than more than $1$, so it is unlikely to be the correct approach

Comment: Do the tortoises appear regularly (every $40$ months) or according to some random process?

Comment: I would have thought that the average number of tortoises in the zoo over time is $30\times 0.3=9$.  Perhaps you could combine this with a Poisson distribution

Comment: Bump! ${}{}{}{}$